# Adding values of dynamic rows not working after multiple dynamic rows are added

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic-tables

I've created a dynamic table where users have to enter the student name and their subject and marks. Each student can contain several subjects. I have attached the code below, which would be easier to understand.

[**Click here to view the working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/soumyar/4Lfmq0pf/)

> **What is working :**

The sum is working perfectly fine for 1 block of students that is added.

> **What I need**

The sum should add for each block of students that I dynamically add and dispaly the totals in sub-total. 
The sub-totals should add to give the total.

> **Code**

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".marks").each(function () {

        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    $("#Sub").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    $("#Sub1").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

function recalc() {
    var tt = 0;
    $("#tb").find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input.row-total').val(dateTotal ? dateTotal : "");
        tt += isNumber(dateTotal) ? dateTotal : 0;
    }); //END .each
    $("#table-grand-total").html(tt);
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".row-total").each(function () {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $(".table-total").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: its correct that every + append to the end of the table??

Comment: @Vanojx1 Didn't quite get what you asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ve some problems in your code:

- You re using ids while working with dynamic items, use class instead
- table footer goes outside the table body
- i always avoid cloning elemets in dynamic tables, you can create tamplates instead
- event bindings

look at my example:

```js
$(function() {
  var students = 0;

  function studentTemplate(students) {

    return '<tr class="student_name"> <td colspan="2"><b>Student Name</b></td><td colspan="1"> <input type="text" name="student_names[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"> </td><th><a style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" class="newstudent" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th> </tr><tr class="student_marks"> <td><b>Subject Name and Marks</b></td><td> <input type="text" name="subnames[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject Name"> </td><td> <input type="number" name="marks[]" class="marks student_' + students + ' form-control" student_ref="student_' + students + '" placeholder="Marks"> </td><th><a style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" class="addsubject" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th> </tr><tr class="subtotal"> <td colspan="2"><b>Sub - Total</b></td><td> <input type="text" name="subtotals[]" class="row-total student_' + students + ' form-control" disabled> </td></tr>';

  }

  function subTemplate(students) {
    return '<tr class="student_marks"> <td><b>Subject Name and Marks</b></td><td> <input type="text" name="subnames[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject Name"> </td><td> <input type="number" name="marks[]" class="marks student_' + students + ' form-control" student_ref="student_' + students + '" placeholder="Marks"> </td><th><a style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" class="addsubject" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th> </tr>';

  }

  $('#tb tbody').append(studentTemplate(students));

  $('#tb tbody').on("click", "a.newstudent", function() {
    students++;
    $('#tb tbody').append(studentTemplate(students));
  });

  $('#tb tbody').on("click", "a.addsubject", function() {
    $(this).closest(".student_marks").after(subTemplate(students));
  });

  $('#tb tbody').on("keyup", "input.marks", function() {
    subtotal($(this).attr("student_ref"));
  });

  function subtotal(ref) {
    var sub = 0;
    $(".marks." + ref).each(function() {
      sub += $(this).val() != "" ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
    });
    $(".row-total." + ref).val(sub);
    calcTotal();
  }

  function calcTotal() {
    var total = 0
    $(".row-total").each(function() {
      total += $(this).val() != "" ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
    })

    $('#table-grand-total').val(total);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <div class="Container">
      <table class="table table-hover small-text" style="margin-top: 50px;" id="tb" border="1px">
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <th colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="GrandTotal[]" id="table-grand-total" class="table-total form-control" disabled>
          </td>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```